# xcorr between two matrices

Tags: matlab, matrix, cross-correlation

I have a question on `xcorr` function in MATLAB.

Currently this function can calculate the autocorrelation of a matrix, but cannot calculate the cross-correlation of 2 matrices:

```
A=[1,2;3,4];
B=[5,6;7,8];

xcorr(A); %% Possible
xcorr(A,A); %% Not Possible
xcorr(A,B); %% Not Possible
```

Are you aware of any workaround to do this, but without using a `for` loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`xcorr` has essentially two syntaxes.

```
c = xcorr(x, y)
```

computes the cross-correlation function between two scalar signals (given as vectors), and

```
c = xcorr(x)
```

computes the auto-correlation function of a signal if `x` is a vector, and the auto- and cross-correlation functions between all columns of `x` if it is a matrix. If `x` is of size `n` x `p`, then `c` is of size `2*n-1` x `p^2`.

When you write

```
c = xcorr(x, y);
```

with *two matrices* `x` and `y`, I assume you want the cross-correlation functions between all signals in `x` with all signals in `y`. `xcorr` can't do this out of the box. However, if the two matrices both have `n` rows, you can write

```
c = xcorr([x, y]);
```

to get the auto- and cross-correlation functions between all signals that are in `x` *or* `y`. `c` is of size `2*n-1` x `(p1+p2)^2`, where `p1` and `p2` are the numbers of signals (columns) in the two matrices. You can then reshape and truncate the result:

```
c = reshape(c, 2*n-1, p1+p2, p1+p2);
c = c(:, 1 : p1, p1+1 : end);
```

The result is a three-dimensional matrix where the first dimension corresponds to the lag, the second enumerates the signals in `x` and the third enumerates the signals in `y`; its size is `2*n-1*` x `p1` x `p2`.

Answer (score 2):

To handle cross correlation between matrices just use the 2d version of it: [xcorr2](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/signal/ref/xcorr2.html).

So to calculate autocorrelation just do

```
xcorr2(A)
```

while to find the cross correlation of two matrices

```
xcorr2(A,B)
```

For example, with your A,B the result is:

```
 8    23    14
30    70    38
18    39    20
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. what is cool with the xcorr is that i can consider the matrices as sets of 1D signals (as it is in my case). So the Output of autocorrelation from xcorr is a matrix (2L-1, L*L). I guess with xcorr2 i can gain one nest of for-loop, but still i think there is some missing functionality...

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone finds this searching for the same question, here's an implementation of `xcorr` that will work for lagged cross-correlation of all columns of matrix `A` with all columns of matrix `B`. Much like Donda's answer, except it avoids the 4x unnecessary computation of the unwanted column comparisons. This code is mostly stripped out and modified from the built-in MATLAB `xcorr` function.

```
function C = xcorrAB(A, B, maxlag)
% like xcorr but computed between all the columns of A and the columns of B.
% A and B must have the same number of rows
%
% C is 2*maxlag-1 x size(A, 2)*size(B, 2). 
% You may want to call reshape(C, [], size(A, 2), size(B, 2)) to make the 
% output more straightforward to use

    [m,n] = size(A);
    assert(size(B, 1) == m, 'A and B must have same number of rows');

    if nargin < 3
        maxlag = m - 1;
    end
    mxl = min(maxlag,m - 1);

    m2 = findTransformLength(m);

    XA = fft(A,m2,1);
    XB = fft(B,m2,1);
    C = reshape(XA,m2,1,n).*conj(XB(:,:));

    % Call IFFT and force real output if x is real.
    c1 = ifft(C,[],1,'symmetric');
    % c1 is M2-by-N-by-N.
    % Keep only the lags we want, and move the negative lags before the
    % positive lags. Also flatten the result to 2-D.
    C = [c1(m2 - mxl + (1:mxl),:); c1(1:mxl+1,:)];

end

function m = findTransformLength(m)
    m = 2*m;
    while true
        r = m;
        for p = [2 3 5 7]
            while (r > 1) && (mod(r, p) == 0)
                r = r / p;
            end
        end
        if r == 1
            break;
        end
        m = m + 1;
    end
end
```

Hope this helps!